# Uploading to the App Store

Tags: ios, application-loader, xcode-organizer

So I was wondering which way is the right way to upload an app to the app store?
Is it by using the Application Loader app that apple provides us with
or is it by using the Submit feature in the Xcode organizer?
Or does both work?

The question is for both Mac OS X Apps and iOS Apps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can upload it using both ways, it is up to you. You upload either via the organizer using an Archive build or using the Application loader uising a compressed release build. I have tried both methods and I personally think that it is easier using xcode's organizer. But again this is all up to you. Sometimes you can have problems with the organizer, or you get errors back, if that happens then try using Application Loader. I haven't had any problems with Application Loader yet. So overall lets say, Application loader is the classic, safe but longer way, xcode's organizer is the easy and fast, but sometimes buggy way. Aswell I have encountered a problem where i couldn't build for Archiving, the 'Build for Archiving' button in the build tab was not enabled and I couldnt use the organizer, that's when I used Application Loader and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

There are significant differences which I've tried to list below (as of Xcode 6.3.2 - Jun 2015):

**Xcode Organiser**

- The application to submit must be selected from the list of your locally archived apps (you cannot browse to a specfic file)
- Gives option to 'Validate' your app before submitting
- At validate/submission time will download/sync all the provisioning profiles associated with the selected Apple developer account and re-sign/re-embed the application with the appropriate one (it does indicate which one's get selected but you cannot override this)
- Gives option to automatically upload the debugging symbols that are included in the archived application
- NO upload progress
- (Gives the option to Export to an *.ipa which could be used with Application Loader)

**Application Loader**

- Requires you browse to an *.ipa file for its input
- No option to Validate before submitting
- Uses the provisioning profile that is already embedded in the *.ipa file
- NO way to upload debugging symbols
- Gives upload progress

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the Application Loader to select your binary and submit to iTunes Connect. Xcode can submit, but I personally think that Application Loader is less buggy for it has been around for 3+ years.

Comment: Ok, If I'm going to upload a mac app using Application Loader what file should be uploaded? The .pkg file of the app or the .app file in a .zip?

Answer (score 0):

Same exact thing (starting with Xcode 4).  Do as you wish.

I invite you to read [iTunes Connect's manual](http://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf), as it will probably answers some of your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Both work fine for uploading. I used to use the application loader every time, but the organization technique seems better. The most important reason is because it keeps track of the builds you shipped.

Otherwise it's super easy to overwrite an old dSYM file. That really sucks because then you lose your ability to easily debug crash reports your users send you.